# Quarkus native image build fails

Tags: java, quarkus, graalvm

When I am building a native image build I am facing an issue with reflection

> com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.DeletedElementException: Unsupported field java.lang.Class.newInstanceCallerCache is reachable: The declaring class of this element has been substituted, but this element is not present in the substitution class

How can I fix it? My environment GraalVM 20 and Zulu OpenJdk11

My pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>qd</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <properties>
        <quarkus.version>1.3.0.Final</quarkus.version>
        <surefire.version>2.22.2</surefire.version>
        <mybatis.version>3.5.4</mybatis.version>
        <mybatis.cdi.version>1.1.1</mybatis.cdi.version>
        <kafka.version>2.4.1</kafka.version>
        <resteasy.version>4.5.3.Final</resteasy.version>
        <mongo.version>3.12.2</mongo.version>
        <testcontainer.version>1.13.0</testcontainer.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-flyway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-agroal</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-config-yaml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-mutiny</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-mongodb-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-jwt</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>${mybatis.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>${mybatis.cdi.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- to fix bug with reactive -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-context-propagation</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${mongo.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>
                        11
                    </release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
                <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-index</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jandex</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <properties>
                <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you post your pom.xml file? Are you using dependencies that are not Quarkus extensions? Is it working in JVM mode?

Comment: You are using some non-Quarkus dependencies, I would try to remove all of these and add one by one and check which one is causing the error (it could be more than one).

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, removing non-quarkus dependencies can help.

There are also libraries in your dependencies which have a quarkus equivalent, for example `kafka-client`. Try substituting those with the quarkus equivalent.

Here a link to said library:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-kafka-client

It's hard to tell which dependency causes the problem excatly, but I would suggest to substitute the ones that are possible, and if the problem persists you can try removing the remaining dependencies.